# Is there a website for the Tatra mountains Polish shelters?

Tags: online-resources, poland, sleeping, tatras

I am trying to look for the Tatra mountain shelters. I want to check location, prices, and maybe do a reservation.

Is there a website?

Comment: like this http://www.discoverzakopane.com/schren.html ?

Comment: Ah, yes.. that's great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polish mountain shelters are operated by [PTTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTTK) (Polish Tourist and Sightseeing Society).

They have site with list of [their shelters in Tarta mountains](http://www.schroniska-pttk.com.pl//index.php?lang=en). By clicking `More` you get detailed description, contact and price information.